# Reason of ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot the output of the function defined below,but not able to get the output. I tried several things but getting different errors every time. If somebody can help me with what it is that I am doing wrong, I shall be grateful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import math
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x',positive = True)
lambd = 4
a= 3
def f(x):
    return lambd**a * x**(a-1) * sym.exp(-lambd*x) / math.factorial(a-1)
x1 = np.linspace(0,1,10)
plt.plot(x1,f(x1))
```

In case I change the `x1` as `np.linspace(0,1,100)` then the error is
 `"ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32"`

What can be the reason for that? Some guidance in this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a numpy array `x1` to a function `f`. The problem that inside this function you have `sympy.exp()` which does not understand what to do with an array, since it only works on symbols and numbers.

The easiest would be to use `numpy.exp` instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

lambd = 4
a= 3

def f(x):
    return lambd**a * x**(a-1) * np.exp(-lambd*x) / math.factorial(a-1)

x1 = np.linspace(0,1,10)
plt.plot(x1,f(x1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

If, for whatever reason, you need to use some function that only works on single numbers and not arrays, you can use `numpy.vectorize` to convert the function to one that evaluates the input array elementwise.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
import math

lambd = 4
a= 3

def f(x):
    return lambd**a * x**(a-1) * sym.exp(-lambd*x) / math.factorial(a-1)

fv = np.vectorize(f)

x1 = np.linspace(0,1,10)
plt.plot(x1,fv(x1))

plt.show()
```